# Discord.js How to get show your server member count from your bot

Tags: node.js, discord.js, replit

I've been trying to show my server member count from my bot but I don't know the input to type.

```
const {MessageEmbed} = require("discord.js")
module.exports.run = async (client, message, args) => {
  console.log(message.guild.iconURL())
  const messageEmbed = new MessageEmbed()
  .setTitle(" Server Information ")
  .setThumbnail(message.guild.iconURL())
  .addFields(
    {name: "Server Name:", value: `\`${message.guild.name}\``, inline: true},
    {name: "Server Owner:", value: `${message.guild.owner}`, inline: true},
    {name: "Server Created:", value: `${message.guild.createdAt}`},
    {name: "Emoji count:", value: `${message.guild.emojis.cache.size}`, inline: true},
    {name: "Member count:", value: `${message.guild.members}`, inline: true}
  )
  .setColor("#FFFF66")
  .setFooter("Requested by " + message.author.tag)
  .setTimestamp()

  message.channel.send(messageEmbed)
}


exports.help = {
    name: "serverinfo"
}
```

I have a feeling that `${message.guild.members}` is wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`Message`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message) has no `members` property. What you need to do is get the [`Guild`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Guild) class from [`Message#guild`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=guild) and access its [`memberCount`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Guild?scrollTo=memberCount) property.

```js
{name: "Member count:", value: message.guild.memberCount, inline: true}
```

Note that you should request the `GUILDS` and `GUILD_MEMBERS` intents when creating your client. For example:

```js
const client = new Discord.Client({
    intents: ['GUILDS', 'GUILD_MEMBERS']
});
```

---

To filter members from bots you can use [`Collection#filter`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/collection/stable/class/Collection?scrollTo=filter):

```js
const members = message.guild.members.cache.filter(member => !member.user.bot);
const bots = message.guild.members.cache.filter(member => member.user.bot);

console.log(`There are ${members.size} members and ${bots.size} bots in this server.`);
```

Comment: how do i filter members from the bots?

Comment: @Itzkaiiii I've added an example to my answer.

Comment: Sadly I get this: [Here](https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/924212256835780638/926820013640396830/unknown.png)

Comment: You forgot to access the `.size` property. `members` and `bots` are Maps. Use `members.size` and `bots.size`.

Comment: i think i'm doin smthn wrong. ``{name: "Members:", value: `${message.guild.members.cache.filter(member => !member.user.bot).size}`, inline: true},`` . It just shows up like [this](https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/924212256835780638/926823553750429726/unknown.png)

Comment: Yup. All you have to do now is request the `GUILD_MEMBERS` intent so all the members are cached, not just the bot. [`Read more.`](https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/intents.html#enabling-intents)